# Using prp after loading rpart.plot

Tags: r, rpart

I'm a new R user and my end goal is to use prp.  I've used the below code to install rpart.plot.  What changes do I need to make to my code so I can use prp?

```
install.packages("rpart.plot", lib = "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\rpart.plot_2.1.2") 
?prp

output: No documentation for ‘prp’ in specified packages and libraries:
you could try ‘??prp’
```

Comment: Maybe see here - https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rpart.plot/rpart.plot.pdf

Comment: it appears you have neither loaded the package nor read an intro to r paper

Answer (score 1):

Do this at R command prompt:

```
library(rpart.plot) # load rpart.plot package
?prp                # get help page for prp 
                    # (but I suggest you use rpart.plot until more experienced)

# simple example:
data(ptitanic)      # load the ptitanic data
mod <- rpart(survived ~ ., data=ptitanic)
rpart.plot(mod)     # plot the model

example(rpart.plot) # further examples
```

This assumes that you have already installed the rpart.plot package using install.packages().  You only have to install the package once, and thereafter just use library(rpart.plot) to use it.